# trackbar add remove "button"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть функция для создания кнопки

```
public button addButton(string nameBtn, Image img)
        {
            button btn = new button();
            btn.Name = nameBtn;
            btn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
            btn.BackgroundImage = img;
            btn.Height = 55;
            btn.Width = 55;
            btn.AllowDrop = true;
            return btn;
        }
```

Я её использую для создания\удаления кнопок на панели - `FlowLayoutPanel`, следующим образом:

```
panelControl.Controls.Add(addButton("NameButton", IMAGE);
panelControl.Controls.Remove(panelControl.Controls[index]);
```

Где индекс - `int index = panelControl.Controls.Count - 1;` т.е. каждый раз удаляю последнюю кнопку на панели(вроде очень удобно).

Мозг выдумал идею - использовать для создания кнопок `trackBar` по событию - `Scroll`, но вот незадача, каким образом это осуществить? Массив не подходит. `List<Button>` - тоже не подходит(для меня). Если без них никак я перекрою программу(ок), но мб просто глаза замылились и есть более простое решение?

UDP:
Сохранять каждый раз положение `TrackBar'a`? И от него плясать если увеличивается то `.add` иначе `.remove`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете подробнее описать, что вы делаете? Просто не совсем понятно, зачем вам при прокрутке кнопки добавлять и удалять. И чем вам не подходил `List`?

Comment: Не нравится `List` - познакомьтесь с `BindingList` и привязками данных `INotifyPropertyChanged`, тогда вам откроется новая вселенная возможностей. А так, у вас есть 2 метода `Add` и `Remove`, и совершенно без разницы, откуда из какого обработчика события их вызывать, это никак не должно менять структур данных и подхода к реализации. Либо плохо объяснили, что именно нужно делать по скроллу.

Comment: И вы верно рассуждаете, у трэкбара есть значение, левая и правая граница, которые вы можете сами задать. Прочитав значение, можно узнать сколько кнопок требуется. Затем убрать лишние и добавить новые по разнице с количеством текущим кнопок в коллекции.

Comment: @aepot, я дополнил ответ, описывать весь процесс было бы утомительно поэтому гиф. Но после нескольких дней отдыха и раздумий я все же ссылаюсь на работу с коллекциями или с массивами кнопок. В любом случае как работает сейчас - я использую .config для сохранения путей к .exe файлам и сохранения имен кнопок для их идентификации, и при старте программы создаю кнопки с нуля навешивая на них иконки программ через сохраненные пути, собственно так же и открываю программы с панели. Сейчас создать кнопку гор. клавиша "N" удалить - "Delete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью дополнительной глобальной переменной

```
private int NumberOfButton = 0;
```

В методе загрузки формы получаю изначальное кол-во кнопок на панели

```
Form1 main = Owner as Form1;
NumberOfButton = main.numberBtn;
```

При использовании Scroll'a получилось примерно следующее:

```
            int index = trackBar1.Value;
        
            if(trackBar1.Value > NumberOfButton)
            {
                //... Add Button
                NumberOfButton++;
            }
            else
            {               
                //... Delete Button
                NumberOfButton--;                 
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]